# Find a point position on a rotated rectangle not knowing the angle

Tags: geometry

I have a similar question to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37526/find-a-point-position-on-a-rotated-rectangle), except that I don't know the rotation angle. I just need to put the upper left corner of the rotated rectangle to (Xmin, Ymin). How can I calculate the rotated position B from the original position A?

[image: Illustration]

Comment: I suggest to put the rectangle in the middle of the image and actually rotate around the center of the rectangle. That would make calculations a lot easier (its only $(r\cos \alpha, r\sin \alpha)$ where $r$ is the distance from the center to the corner and $\alpha$ a respective angle to a corner.

Comment: Oh, never thought of it. Thanks, will do!